# Creating a function of sum of elements of vectors in r

Tags: r, matrix, vector

so I created this function in r:

```
v=1:4
h = function(x){sum(exp(x*v))}
```

why is this not working? and what can make it work in a simple form?

x*v should be (x,2x,3x,4x) and exp(x*v) should be (exp(x),..,exp(4x)) and this should work.

EDIT:

Sorry if my originally question seemed invalid because this function does not generate any error message. However, plot(h) has issues, which should not be. And a lot of advance interactions with other commands will have issues in one way or another.

Comment: `h <- function(x){sum(exp(x * 1:4))}` / `h <- function(x){sum(exp(x*v))}` / `h <- function(x, v){sum(exp(x*v))}`

Comment: @brittenb from the expected output, `xv`, it seems like the vector should be `length(v)`

Comment: @rawr Possibly. I see where you'd get that. My interpretation is that `exp(xv)` should be equal to `c(exp(x), exp(2*x), exp(3*x), exp(4*x))`, which would then be inserted into the `sum` function.

Comment: Wait, the OP's function works fine for me. Or is it not giving the desired result? If so, what is the desired result?

Comment: Indeed, it *is working*, but apparently not as desired. What is the input and expected output?

Comment: It indeed is working on the surface level. But plot(h) fails. And a lot of advance interactions with other commands such as outer(1:3,1:4,g), where
g = function(x,y){sum(exp(x*y*c)) also fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just Vectorize the function.

Link: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Vectorize.html

UPDATE: ok, some code

There are no numbers in **R**, only vectors. Numbers are atomic vectors of length one. So, each function should expect to have vector as input and produce vector as output. All standard functions and operations are vectorized.

Take your function and put some `print`s in

```
h <- function(x){
    print(x)
    print(x*v)
    print(exp(x*v))        
    sum(exp(x*v))
}
```

One can see that calling `h(0.5)` will produce single value of `x`, vector of 4
for a product of `v*x`, vector of 4 for exponent and then return single value as result of the sum. On my computer

```
[1] 0.5
[1] 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0
[1] 1.648721 2.718282 4.481689 7.389056
[1] 16.23775
```

Call like `h(c(0.5))` will produce ABSOLUTELY THE SAME result. Ok, so far so good. But! If you call it with vector like `h(c(0.5, 1.0))`, you'll get single value, which is just wrong.

So, how to fix it - Vectorize!

```
hh <- Vectorize(h)

hh(c(0.5, 1.0))
```

Call to `hh(c(0.5, 1.0))` will produce right result, namely, vector, with output

```
[1] 0.5
[1] 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0
[1] 1.648721 2.718282 4.481689 7.389056
[1] 1
[1] 1 2 3 4
[1]  2.718282  7.389056 20.085537 54.598150
[1] 16.23775 84.79102
```